# account ids obtained from /accounts/get for a access token is not matching account ids inside transactions obtained from /transactions/get

Tags: plaid

none of the account ids obtained from /accounts/get for a access token is matching account ids inside transactions obtained from /transactions/get

This is confusing me because how can a user have performed a transaction with an account id that is not registered with the particular bank?

Environment: sandbox
institution_id: "ins_1"

Comment: Can you update your question to provide your requests (with secret, access token, and key redacted) and responses that you are asking about?

Comment: So, I found the solution, for those of you who run into the same problem in the future, change the institution id to any of the institution ids provided in the sandbox endpoints documentation, and the data in those (fictional) banks were correct (matching account_id fields)